# Replacing the space character with underscore within a matched group?

Tags: python, regex

I have a string that looks something like this:

`"(case when Campaign='Back to School' and VariableName='Total_FB_Spend' then VariableValue else 0 end) AS Back to School_Total_FB_Spend,(case when Campaign='Back to School' and VariableName='Total_FB_Imp' then VariableValue else 0 end) AS Back to School_Total_FB_Imp"`

I would like to use Python regex to remove spaces in the column names after 'end) AS ' character. The result should become something like this

`"(case when Campaign='Back to School' and VariableName='Total_FB_Spend' then VariableValue else 0 end) AS Back_to_School_Total_FB_Spend,(case when Campaign='Back to School' and VariableName='Total_FB_Imp' then VariableValue else 0 end) AS Back_to_School_Total_FB_Imp"`

I am able to match those parts that I am interested using regex in Python [[example here]](http://pythex.org/?regex=(end%5C)%20as%20)(.*%3F(%2C%7C%24))&test_string=(case%20when%20Campaign%3D%27Back%20to%20School%27%20and%20VariableName%3D%27Total_FB_Spend%27%20then%20VariableValue%20else%200%20end)%20as%20Back%20to%20School_Total_FB_Spend%2C(case%20when%20Campaign%3D%27Back%20to%20School%27%20and%20VariableName%3D%27Total_FB_Imp%27%20then%20VariableValue%20else%200%20end)%20as%20Back%20to%20School_Total_FB_Imp&ignorecase=0&multiline=0&dotall=1&verbose=0) But I would like to know how to elegantly (e.g., one liner or in a Pythonic way) substitute space characters in groups that matches.

Comment: Please check my answer below. Note that while a lookbehind-based regex will be more optimal in this case, I decided to introduce as few changes to the original pattern itself as possible to show how *multiple* groups can be handled in a single lambda replacement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a `re.sub` with a lambda expression as the replacement argument:

```
import re
s = "(case when Campaign='Back to School' and VariableName='Total_FB_Spend' then VariableValue else 0 end) AS Back to School_Total_FB_Spend,(case when Campaign='Back to School' and VariableName='Total_FB_Imp' then VariableValue else 0 end) AS Back to School_Total_FB_Imp"
pat = r'(end\) as )([^,]*)'
print(re.sub(pat, lambda m: "{}{}".format(m.group(1), m.group(2).replace(" ", "_")), s))
```

See the [Python demo](http://ideone.com/MAZwn4)

Note that I replaced your `(.*?(,|$))` with a more efficient `([^,]*)`, any zero or more chars other than `,`. Now, the whole regex matches:

- `(end\) as )` - Group 1: `end) as`
- `([^,]*)` - Group 2: any zero or more chars other than `,`

Then, with `lambda m: "{}{}".format(m.group(1), m.group(2).replace(" ", "_"))`, the contents of the first  capturing group is copied back to the result unchanged, and the second group contents are modified with `.replace(" ", "_")`. Certainly, you may run another regex on it if there may be any whitespace, `re.sub(r'\s+', '_', m.group(2))`.

Comment: Stribizew Thank you so much for the detailed explanation of how pieces work together in your suggested solution!! It works like a charm. I ended up using `re.sub(r'\W+', '_', m.group(2))` because it's easier. I'm not very familiar with `lambda` yet, so I wonder how it is returning groups that matches the regex pattern (without us writing anything explicit like `re.search(pat, s)` within the `lambda` statement). If you don't mind explaining that further or direct me to a good resource, which explains that, I'd greatly appreciate it! :)

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed explanation! Your answers are very helpful and clear because of the patient/detail explanation. Today I learned that `re.sub` passes the matched objects into `lambda` (or `lambda` captures whatever matches in `re.sub`). Very powerful!

Comment: Sorry for formatting. Reposting the comment: Actually, the `m` in the lambda stands for a match data object. When you use `re.sub`, the regex engine searches for all non-overlapping occurrences of the pattern, and when a match is found, all the capturing group form `.group()`s. So, `(a)|(b)` contains 2 capturing groups, and when used on an `abc` string, first, `a` is found (with `a` in `m.group(1)` and null/empty (depending on Python version) in `m.group(2)`). You may access any capturing group or the whole match (`m.group()`), and do whatever you please (cast to int, increment, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

Another solution inspired by @Wiktor.

```
import re
s = "(case when Campaign='Back to School' and VariableName='Total_FB_Spend' then VariableValue else 0 end) AS Back to School_Total_FB_Spend,(case when Campaign='Back to School' and VariableName='Total_FB_Imp' then VariableValue else 0 end) AS Back to School_Total_FB_Imp"
pat = r'(?<=end\) as )[\w\s]*(?=,)'
print(re.sub(pat, lambda m: m.group(0).replace(" ", "_"), s, flags=re.IGNORECASE))
```

Here we use the lookahead and lookbehind feature of regex to only match the substring we want to alter. The regex will match any sequence of **word characters** `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` and **spaces** preceded by `end ) as`, and followed by `,`. The main difference is that the match will only contain a single group.

Comment: Just note that a lookbehind is not that flexible as a capturing group as a lookbehind pattern should be of fixed length. You cannot use `\s*` nor `\w+` there.

Comment: Indeed, but as we are looking for a fixed suffix and postfix this will no be a problem in this scenario.

Comment: @Jonas Thank you for the alternative suggestion. I learned a bit about lookahead/lookbehind pattern in regex for the first time here. When I tried the code you shared above though, I received `IndexError: no such group`.

Comment: My bad, I did some cleaning without testing. `group(0)` contains the full match, and consecutive indexes will contain the subgroups if any such exists. When I removed the parentheses around `[\w\s]` i also removed the subgroup.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`bytes.replace()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=replace#bytes.replace) function.

```
'Back to School'.replace(' ', '_')
```